# ios magicalRecord not assigning string value to property

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I have problem assigning a NSString value to a property of my model class. When I NSLog the string out, it is there, but when I try to assign the string to a property and then log out the property, its always null, could you please help me with that?

The property I am trying to assign a value to is defined like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;
```

I am assigning the value like so:

```
NSString *categoryText = [self.pickerCategoryText objectAtIndex:[self.categoryPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
newFilter.category.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", categoryText];
```

I have also tried to alloc and init the property and also assign the value like so:

```
newFilter.category.text = categoryText;
```

but none of these solutions worked. I am now totally lost and without any other possible clues, could you please help me with that ?

Thx

Comment: Check if `newFilter.category` is not `nil`? Where(which method) you are assigning text property?

Comment: You are right, I totally forgot to create the category and then assign it a value.. if you post it as an answer I will accept it. thx

Comment: Also, there's no need to format a string with itself. In this case, just assign the string to the property straight up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time when you perform:

```
newFilter.category.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", categoryText];
```

... either `newFilter` or `category` might be `nil`. If they are `nil` nothing gets changed.